# List of installed fonts OS X / C

Tags: python, c, macos, fonts

I'm trying to programatically get a list of installed fonts in C or Python. I need to be able to do this on OS X, does anyone know how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Python with PyObjC installed (which is the case for Mac OS X 10.5+, so this code will work without having to install anything):

```
import Cocoa
manager = Cocoa.NSFontManager.sharedFontManager()
font_families = list(manager.availableFontFamilies())
```

(based on htw's answer)

Answer (score 9):

Why not use the Terminal?

**System Fonts:**

```
ls -R /System/Library/Fonts | grep ttf
```

**User Fonts:**

```
ls -R ~/Library/Fonts | grep ttf
```

**Mac OS X Default fonts:**

```
ls -R /Library/Fonts | grep ttf
```

If you need to run it inside your C program:

```
void main()
{ 
    printf("System fonts: ");
    execl("/bin/ls","ls -R /System/Library/Fonts | grep ttf", "-l",0);
    printf("Mac OS X Default fonts: ");
    execl("/bin/ls","ls -R /Library/Fonts | grep ttf", "-l",0);
    printf("User fonts: ");
    execl("/bin/ls","ls -R ~/Library/Fonts | grep ttf", "-l",0);
}
```

Comment: That's not the only place you can find fonts: there's also `/System/Library/Fonts` and `~/Library/Fonts`...

Comment: There are also OpenType fonts (otf) in addition to TrueType (ttf).

Comment: Also, this doesn't factor that some fonts might be installed but disabled, and thus not available to the system. Using FontManager gives you fonts that are available, i.e. enabled.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly C, but in Objective-C, you can easily get a list of installed fonts via the Cocoa framework:

```
// This returns an array of NSStrings that gives you each font installed on the system
NSArray *fonts = [[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] availableFontFamilies];

// Does the same as the above, but includes each available font style (e.g. you get
// Verdana, "Verdana-Bold", "Verdana-BoldItalic", and "Verdana-Italic" for Verdana).
NSArray *fonts = [[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] availableFonts];
```

You can access the Cocoa framework from Python via [PyObjC](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/), if you want.

In C, I think you can do something similar in Carbon with the ATSUI library, although I'm not entirely sure how to do this, since I haven't worked with fonts in Carbon before. Nevertheless, from browsing the ATSUI docs, I'd recommend looking into the [`ATSUGetFontIDs`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/ATSUI_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ATSUGetFontIDs) and the [`ATSUGetIndFontName`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/ATSUI_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ATSUGetIndFontName) functions. Here's a link to the [ATSUI documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/ATSUI_Reference/Reference/reference.html) for more information.

Comment: ATSUI was removed in OSX 10.15.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to *write* a program to do it, or do you want to *use* a program to do it?  There are many programs that list fonts, xlsfonts comes to mind.

Comment: He said *programmatically*, so I assume he wants to write a program to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of available fonts using Objective-C and Cocoa. The method you are looking for is [`NSFontManager`'s `availableFonts`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfontmanager/1462372-availablefonts?language=objc).

I don't believe there is a standard way to determine what the system fonts are using pure C. However, you can freely mix C and Objective-C, so it really shouldn't be to hard to use this method to do what you'd like.