# Trying to write Python script to remove duplicate fonts Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, fonts, pyobjc

I am trying to write a utility to check through the fonts on OSX and remove duplicates - so far I've had success iterating through the folder structure and writing out an xml file containing fonts and paths. The drawback is that this doesn't find duplicates as the same font can be installed twice in different locations but with a different file name; font family information is internal to the font file.

I have found this: [List of installed fonts OS X / C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113040/list-of-installed-fonts-os-x-c)

```
import Cocoa
manager = Cocoa.NSFontManager.sharedFontManager()
font_families = list(manager.availableFontFamilies())
```

Which uses PyObjC to list installed fonts. This looks like a possible solution but I'm not a heavy weight coder and know nothing about PyObjC! I did have a play around in a terminal with `dir(manager)`and `dir(NSFontManager)`to see if I could find a method that returned the file paths of installed fonts but to no avail.

Any help gratefully received.

Best wishes

//Simon

Comment: The same font can be installed at least three times with the _same_ name: /System/Library/Fonts, /Library/Fonts, ~/Library/Fonts. Additionally, you can have fonts within subfolders, so you could store the same font (with the same name) in subfolders of any of the above.

Comment: Font Book comes with Mac OS X and can check for font duplicates.

Comment: Hello LaC - yes, I've been using Font Book. The reason for writing the script is that it's for my wife, who is a graphic designer, and there are some 3000 fonts on her Mac! Font book has a bit of a reputation for not being too hot - if you Google around the design forums you will find a lot of chat on the subject, but thank you for the message.

Comment: Hi Seth - thank you, what you are describing is valid too - the puzzle exists from both angles as it were - duplicate fonts with the same file name, duplicate fonts with a different file name...

Answer (score 1):

Install the `fonttools` package and take a look at this [blog post](http://starrhorne.com/posts/font_name_from_ttf_file/). There's a script there that gives the font name of its first argument and I'm sure you could adapt it to your use case.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll give it a go as soon I have a moment - I'll try and find some fonttools reference as I'm not just dealing with .ttf but also .otf and other font types so hope it will do the job..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks once again for the replies - I just wanted to update this in the hope it helps. I'm looking at fontTools now, but admit I am having trouble finding documentation. According to the developer's page there are libraries to handle other fonts apart from ttf, but I'm still looking with little success just yet!

**In the mean time**, I did turn up this page on [Using Apple Font tools](http://www.fontgeek.net/blog/?p=104), which seems get half way to what I need - ie listing installed fonts and locations. It looks like the `ftxinstalledfonts` command will accept a pipe so in theory I could pipe the output to my existing python script that builds an xml database. I'm assuming I can do this by calling `ftxinstalledfonts` via the sys module but am not clear as to how to get the output... I'll go and plunder the python docs but if there's no luck and someone has 10 secs to give a pointer I'd be grateful.

As a quick aside, the Font Geek site above has some very useful stuff about TTX as well.

Best wishes

//Simon

Comment: Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, not a forum. That said, this does not look like an answer. Either way, read the [FAQ] and if this is indeed a follow-up to your question, either edit the question to include this info or post a new question.